# setuptools "cannot find -lglfw"

Tags: python, c++, setuptools

I'm trying to make a python c++ extension using setuptools and I'm using glfw in my c++ project.

Here is what my setup.py looks like:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages


module1 = Extension('nerveblox',
       sources = ['main.cpp', 'src/nerveblox_VM.cpp'],
       include_dirs=["include", "lib/glfw/include"],
       #extra_link_args=[ "-lm", "-lGL", "-lGLU", "-lglfw"],
       library_dirs=["lib/glfw"],
       libraries=['glfw']
)


setup (
       name = 'Nerveblox_python_test',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',

       ext_modules = [module1],
       install_requires=[
        'importlib-metadata; python_version == "3.8"',
       ],
)
```

My code works fine as pure c++ using cmake. When I run the above script I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw: No such file or directory
```

I've just downlaoded glfw source, extracted it to `lib/glfw` on my setup.py's directory, then ran `cmake .` and `make` inside `lib/glfw`. It's `.so` and `.a` files are inside `lib/glfw/src`.

Comment: *"It's .so and .a files are inside lib/glfw/src."* - then you should add this folder to `library_dirs` instead of `"lib/glfw"`

Comment: @user7860670 This works! I can't believe it was this simple... But now I'm getting this error: `undefined symbol: XConvertSelection` is this from opengl?

Comment: It is probably from x window.

Comment: @user7860670 What should I link for that?